# TypeError when dividing two integers and printing

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, formatting, typeerror

The program is supposed to take two numbers, divide them in the "findRemainder" function and print the remainder.

```
num1=input("Enter a number: ")
num2=input("Enter the divisor: ")
result = 0
def findRemainder(x, y):
    result = (x%y)
    print(str(result))
findRemainder(num1, num2)
```

However, when the code is ran it returns this error:

line 5, in findRemainder

result = (x%y)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: `input` reads in as a string, you need to convert it to `int` before using in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not converting the string to integer. You have to convert the input string to integer before finding the remainder. Like this,

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the divisor: "))
result = 0

def findRemainder(x, y):
    result = (x % y)
    print(str(result))

findRemainder(num1, num2)
```